# Change image for specific rows in datagridviewimagecolumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

my datagridviewimagecolumn is not programmatically added and also unbounded. But the other files are bounded from my database. I need a simple if clause statement so that the warning image would only appear to rows with stock less than 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by datagridview_cellformatting event

Assumed that you already have your DataGridViewImageColumn in Columnindex(0)

```
Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellFormatting
        Dim sHeader As String = dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

        If sHeader = "stock" Then
            If e IsNot Nothing Then
                If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    If e.Value < 20 then
                        Try

                            Dim img as Bitmap = new Bitmap("c:\images\littlemouse.jpg")

                            // Create DGV Image column                                  

                            dgv.CurrentCell.Value = img;
                            dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = img;

                         Catch ex As FormatException

                            e.Value = ""

                         End Try
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If


    End Sub
```